# What is an appropriate null model for a GAM with spatial autocorrelation fit using mgcv::gamm?

Tags: r, autocorrelation, spatial, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I am interested in comparing the fits of various general additive models to a dataset with strong spatial autocorrelation using the R package `mgcv`. There are no random effects, but I fit using `mgcv::gamm` so I can specify an exponential spatial autocorrelation structure. The data has normal errors, so I can compare model fits using AIC. Typically, for a basic GAM I would specify an intercept only null model `gam(N ~ 1, data = data)` and then compare the AIC to my more complex models with fixed effects to look for improvements. However, `gamm` requires that "models must have at least 1 smooth with unknown smoothing parameter or at least one other random effect". So the model `gamm(N ~ 1, correlation = corExp(form = ~ x+y),data = data)` can't be fit. My question then is, what is the appropriate null model in this case? Should I create a dummy random variable (e.g. a vector of ones) to force the function to fit, or is there a more principled method?

A simple reprex using code from the `gamm` Examples

```
# Create spatially autocorrelated data
set.seed(1);n <- 100
data <- gamSim(2,n=n,scale=0)$data ## standard example
## Now simulate correlated errors...
cstr <- corGaus(.1,form = ~x+z)  
cstr <- Initialize(cstr,data.frame(x=data$x,z=data$z))
V <- corMatrix(cstr) ## correlation matrix for data
Cv <- chol(V)
e <- t(Cv) %*% rnorm(n)*0.05 # correlated errors
## next add correlated simulated errors to expected values to produce response
data$y <- data$f + e

# Runs (albeit with convergence warning)
model <- gamm(y~s(x,z,k=50),correlation=corGaus(.1,form=~x+z),data=data)

# Doesn't run
null.model <- gamm(y~1,correlation=corGaus(.1,form=~x+z),data=data)
```

Any pointers greatly appreciated! Thanks.